# GWT - Obtain Browser Timezone/Timestamp formatting

Tags: gwt, date, timezone, timezone-offset

I send timestamps to my GWT client using GMT/Zulu time, with each string designated as such (ie. 2012-01-19T16:29:18Z, or 4:29pm GMT). How do I show this in the browser in the local timezone? So for me in CST I expect to see 10:29am.

If I do no formatting I get the date as 4:29pm, which I expect, If I use a TimeZone object of TimeZone.createTimeZone(0), I get for some reason 10:29PM (not AM as expected). I suppose I'm supposed to pass in something more meaningful than 0, but how do I obtain the right value for the where the browser is running?

J

Comment: This may be important, I parse in from the REST response using a DateTimeFormat of DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the time-zone offset that is configured in the browser using:

```
Date d = new Date();
d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

It won't give you the timezone name, I don't think that's possible to get.

Do you send the time as a timestamp, or string? I find the best approach is to send UTC timestamps to the client and then format them to whatever zone I need using DateTimeFormat/TimeZone. But I guess that if you are parsing the date string including the offset, you end up with a UTC timestamp anyway.

Comment: That helps. I realized my problem was because the Z (for zulu/gmt time) wasn't getting parsed as part of the date, so it assumed the server response was in local time, messing everything up. Your response helped figure this out.

Comment: That seems to be deprecated, or are you not using `java.util.Date`?

Comment: FYI - this returns the *current* time zone offset.  That is, the offset that applies to the date value used.  It may not be the applicable offset for all dates and times, given that many time zones shift their offset for daylight saving time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the GWT client code to format the time in the browser time zone, you should pass the data from the server to the client as a java.util.Date object.